# Admob issues on Xamarin iOS apps with Admob SDK version 6.12.0

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios8, xamarin, admob, google-dfp

I am currently using the Google AdMob Xamarin component (version 6.12.0 - see https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleadmob) to display DFP interstitials and banner ads (displayed at different points within a tableview) on an iOS app. When I am debugging in Visual Studio 2013 I get the following output:

```
<Google:HTML> You are currently using version 6.12.0 of the SDK, which doesn't
officially support iOS 8. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent
sdk version, 6.12.2, to get iOS 8 support, including a fix for smart banner
rendering in landscape mode. The latest SDK can be downloaded from 
http://goo.gl/iGzfsP. A full list of release notes is available at
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/rel-notes.
```

According to the Xamarin component's page, 6.12.0 does actually support iOS 8. Should I ignore the warning that I am getting? If not, how do I go about using 6.12.2 when the newest version of the component is only 6.12.0? Is it OK to stay with 6.12.0 or will it cause issues?

I have noticed that the banner ads aren't really displaying in the correct location on iOS8, they are slightly to the right and down from where they should be. Is this because of the SDK or some other change in iOS8 regarding how cells are displayed?

Below is how I display the banner ad:

```
public void InitialiseBanner(AdMobView property)
  {
        _bannerViewDelegate = new AdMobBannerViewDelegate();

        _bannerView = new DFPBannerView();


        float x = (CurrentWidth/2) - (AdvertWidth/2);

        _bannerView.RootViewController = this;
        _bannerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        _bannerView.Delegate = _bannerViewDelegate;
        _bannerView.Frame = new RectangleF(x, 5, AdvertWidth, 50);

        View.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, CurrentWidth, 50);
        View.AddSubview(_bannerView);
        _bannerView.AdUnitID = "/**UNITIDREMOVED**/" + property.AdAlias;
        GADRequest request = GADRequest.Request;

        .
        .
        .

        _bannerView.LoadRequest(request);

        View.BringSubviewToFront(_bannerView);

        if (DeviceHelper.IsIos8OrGreater && RespondsToSelector(new Selector("separatorInset")))
        {
            _bannerView.LayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
        }


    }
```

Comment: According to the docs (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/rel-notes) the 6.12.0 version actually supports iOS 8, but maybe they have made some changes to the support.

The Google AdMob 6.12.2 component is scheduled to be released in the first days of January.

Answer (score 0):

As for a normal banner, try loading your AdView Like this:
(This is my working example)

As a class level declaration, type this:

```
    GADBannerView adView;
    bool viewOnScreen = false;

    // Get you own AdmobId from: http://www.google.com/ads/admob/
    const string AdmobId = "<your admob id>";
```

Then in your viewDidLoad you can specify position of your banner and load it:

```
            adView = new GADBannerView (size: GADAdSizeCons.Banner, origin: new PointF (0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height-100)) {
            AdUnitID = AdmobId,
            RootViewController = this
        };

        adView.DidReceiveAd += (sender, args) => {
            if (!viewOnScreen) View.AddSubview (adView);
            viewOnScreen = true;
        };

        adView.LoadRequest (GADRequest.Request);
```

I get the same error as well, but it doesn't actually matter. I also thought first that this was the issue but my setup was a bit wrong, i think that is the same for your code. In my example i just added my AdView to the MainView, but using custom cells you should be able to implement it in your UITable View. Also, have a look at the example provided in the components section. As for displaying DFP interstitials: There has to be something wrong with the setup as well, but i can't see it in the code you provided.